# Send The Enter Key to a Webbrowser1

Tags: delphi, events, browser, key, send

**Hello**.

I tried with ;

```
PostMessage(embeddedwb1.Handle,VK_RETURN,0,0);
sendmessage(embeddedwb1,wm_keyup,vk_return,0);
embeddedwb1.perform(wm_keyup,vk_return,0);
```

but my program doesn't work.
and i tried with ;

```
Keybd_Event(VK_RETURN,   1, 0, 0);
```

my program is worked.but that is code for sending enter key for All Applications.i want to code for just my program.**Thank you for helping me**.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the WebBrowser is focused using `SetFocus(embeddedwb1.Handele)` before calling `Keypd_Event(...)`.

Since you probably want to submit a form, did you consider doing that with the DOM? Here's some code that fills in the selected input field and then submits the first form. This works just fine if you navigate to http://www.google.com, but in the real world you'd need to be a lot more careful (search the input field by class or id, check if there's a form, etc)

```
procedure TForm23.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ((W.Document as IHTMLDocument2).activeElement as IHTMLInputElement).value := 'Search';
  ((W.Document as IHTMLDocument2).forms.item(0, '') as IHTMLFormElement).submit;
end;
```

Comment: thankz but i must click ; input type="submit" id="submitAction" value="Cal"></form> - submitaction button.so i tried ; EmbeddedWb1.OleObject.Document.getElementByID('SubmitAction').click ; - doesn't work.and i tried with embeddedwb1.setfocus before caling keypd event-doesnt work :(

Comment: @Kadir, you submit the form, not the button; Look for the form and call Submit as I did! And what do you mean by "Doesn't work"? It doesn't submit the form? The compiler doesn't like the code?

Comment: @Kadir, "doesn't work" is not helpful. If you need help, you need to provide details.

Answer (score 1):

if Javascript is used for submit form then Cosmin answer doesn't work I think. In this case you must know JS code of the button and execute it from your program. For example; in my page, I use JQuery to submit form. So:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  js_code : string;
  Win : IHTMLWindow2;
begin
  Win := (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).parentWindow;
  js_code := '$("#formlogin").submit();';
  Win.execScript(js_code, 'JavaScript');
end;
```

Comment: Your code does the exact same thing (submits the form using DOM). The only difference is you're using JQuery to search the DOM and then invoke `submit()`. Usually when the form is submit using JavaScript you're calling a JavaScript function that gets a chance to do some validation before truly submitting the form. I'd upvote if the `js_code` showed a function invocation, to make it realistic.

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
PostMessage(EmbeddedWB1.HWND, WM_CHAR, 13, 0);
```

This code send char 13 (Enter code) to EmbeddedWB.

Comment: Explain your reasoning.